# Can't get the branch from which build is done in Team City

Tags: shell, unix, teamcity-9.0

I am using TeamCity as my CI server.I am currently generating apk's for two different branches. Now I need to upload these apk's to hockey-app for two different teams.But I cannot understand whether build is coming from the default branch or release branch.I tried

```
#!/bin/sh    
branch=%teamcity.build.branch%   
echo $branch    
if [ $branch = "default" ]    
then   
echo "got the answer"   
else    
echo "None of the condition met"   
fi
```

Now I am building default branch.But **line 3** is printing **%teamcity.build.branch%** instead of **default**.Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
branch=%teamcity.build.branch%
echo $branch
branch1=release
branch2=default
if [[ "$branch" =~ "$branch1" ]];
then
API_FOR_HOCKEY_APP
elif [[ "$branch" =~ "$branch2" ]];
then
API_FOR_HOCKEY_APP
else
echo "Build is not from any of the branches"
fi
```

If build is from any branch which contains the string release or default in it's name ,it will get uploaded to hockeyapp respectively .